# Video is not expanding to full screen in Extjs window

Tags: video, extjs, window, screen

Plateform : Ext JS 4.2.1

Browser:
Chrome: Version 46.0.2490.86 m
Firefox 40.0.3
IE10, IE11

Requirements:

I am using a HTML 5 video tag inside a EXTJS window html content. I am using custom buttons instead of video controls attribute.

While using the default controls attribute, I am not able to see Expand Full Screen icon in control tray. 
I have added my custom buttons instead of default controls.
Play, Pause and volume buttons are working fine as expected but Full Screen is not working even i have added correct listener to full screen button as shown below

```
// Event listener for the full-screen button

fullScreenButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (video.requestFullscreen) {

        video.requestFullscreen();

    } 
   else if (video.mozRequestFullScreen) {
        video.mozRequestFullScreen(); // Firefox
    }
    else if (video.webkitRequestFullscreen) 
   {
        console.log('fullScreenButton clicked');

        video.webkitRequestFullscreen(); // Chrome and Safari

        console.log('Executed webkitRequestFullscreen()');
    }
    else if (video.msRequestFullscreen) {

        video.msRequestFullscreen(); // Internet Explorer

    }
});
```

Test fiddel https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/118s

[Scenario screenshot is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZA2j2.png)

I want to expand the video in full window screen as expected to do by Full screen button in player. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you open developer console before clicking on full screen button you can see the below message

> Request for fullscreen was denied because at least one of the
>   document’s containing elements is not an iframe or does not have an
>   “allowfullscreen” attribute.

Hope by checking this you can find the solution.